# Bit vs Byte in memory adress?

Tags: memory, operating-system, byte, bit, memory-address

I know that 1 byte = 8 bits.

1. Can I access 1 bits in memory or it should be a full byte?
2. Let's suppose the memory starts at: 0x0000 then what's the next position? 0x0001 or 0x0008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many bit processer you have. I don't think there are any 1-bit processors around.

But a 8-bit processor would read a full byte, and then you can mask bits to actually read the only one you care about.

Therefore, considering the most common architectures, the next address would be 0x0008

Edit: Based on the comments, there are 1-bit processors

Comment: then answers 1 but not 2 :)

Comment: Edited to include no 2

Comment: Thanks, I think this is related too can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586556/intel-x64-why-idt-limit-is-16-bits-idtr-register

Comment: This isn't very true. Modern 32 bits and 64 bits processors are addressed at the byte level. You can access one byte at a time. To modify a bit, you need to access the byte and write it back.

Comment: Each address placed on the address bus identifies one byte.

Comment: There have of course been 1 bit processors such as the famous Motorola MC14500B.

Comment: Meh...8051 has bit addressing, (for data section anyway).